# SQL inner join usage

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, inner-join

I have a query that joins many table and all these tables have a column named businessetityid.So that this column duplicates many times.Is there any simple way to handle this.
Here is my query :

```
SELECT * FROM person p 
inner join personemailaddress e on p.BusinessEntityID=e.BusinessEntityID
inner join personpassword ps on p.BusinessEntityID=ps.BusinessEntityID
inner join personphone ph on p.BusinessEntityID=ph.BusinessEntityID
inner join 
( 
select BusinessEntityID from  businessentityaddress b
inner join address a on b.AdressID=a.AdressID
)  ad on ad.BusinessEntityID=p.BusinessEntityID

INTO OUTFILE 'D:\forMongo.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

I want to get only one businessentityid column in mongodb.csv file.

Comment: Its better to use UPPERCASE for reserved key words for better readability..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented under [`JOIN` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/join.html) (emphasis added):

> The following list provides more detail about several effects of current join processing versus join processing in older versions. The term “previously” means “prior to MySQL 5.0.12.”
>
> - The columns of a `NATURAL` join or a `USING` join may be different from previously. **Specifically, redundant output columns no longer appear**, and the order of columns for `SELECT *` expansion may be different from before.

Therefore, if you specify your join criteria with `USING` instead of `ON`, the repeated columns will be eliminated:

```
SELECT *
FROM   person             p
  JOIN personemailaddress e  USING (BusinessEntityID)
  JOIN personpassword     ps USING (BusinessEntityID)
  JOIN personphone        ph USING (BusinessEntityID)
  JOIN (
         SELECT BusinessEntityID
         FROM   businessentityaddress b
           JOIN address               a USING (AdressID)
       ) USING (BusinessEntityID)
INTO   OUTFILE 'D:\\forMongo.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
       ENCLOSED   BY '"'
LINES  TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Comment: Yes,it worked.This is the shortcut to do this thing right.Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Yes, do not use a `Select *`. Instead list the columns exactly as you want them to appear in your query, making sure to use the correct columns by prefixing them with the table correlation name

For instance

```
SELECT
       e.Town, 
       ph.Mobile 
FROM person p 
inner join personemailaddress e on p.BusinessEntityID=e.BusinessEntityID
inner join personpassword ps on p.BusinessEntityID=ps.BusinessEntityID
inner join personphone ph on p.BusinessEntityID=ph.BusinessEntityID
inner join 
( 
select BusinessEntityID from  businessentityaddress b
inner join address a on b.AdressID=a.AdressID
)  ad on ad.BusinessEntityID=p.BusinessEntityID

INTO OUTFILE 'D:\forMongo.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Comment: Yeah,i know this way but i have 19 columns to get.I hope there are alternative ways simplier to do that.

Comment: @mekafe - what is the problem with listing the columns? justin's answer is a good solution.

Comment: There are no shortcuts when it comes to doing something right.

Comment: @mekafe 19 columns to add is way better than solving problem when something bad happens. Beside it is better performance-wise.